# Does every quasiprojective variety admit a projective closure with smooth complement?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasiprojective variety. Does there exist a projective variety $Y$ and an open dense immersion $X \to Y$ such that $Y \setminus X$ is smooth?  <strike>What if we just require that $Y \setminus X$ be complete intersection?</strike>  (note that a smooth variety is locally complete intersection, but being complete intersection is a stronger condition in the affine sense, and a *much* stronger condition in the projective sense.)

Of course, if you take "the" projective closure of $X$ relative to some embedding in $\mathbb P^n$, it need not have this property. I'm asking if this can be arranged by a suitable choice of embedding.

For example, it might be the case that you just need to take the embedding associated to a sufficiently high twist $\mathcal O(n)$.

Comment: I believe in characteristic zero this can be achieved by resolution of singularities.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! What's the general idea of the construction?

Comment: You take any projective completion and resolve the singularities of the complement of $X$.

Comment: @Mohan I don't understand -- let $Y$ be any projective completion of $X$, let $Z = Y \setminus X$, and let $\tilde Z \to Z$ be a resolution of singularities. Are you saying there's some way to glue $\tilde Z$ and $X$ together? And that the result is projective?

Comment: No, the singular points of $Z$ as points of $X$ are resolved, not just $Z$.

Comment: How does that work e.g. if $X = \mathbb P^2$ and $Z = \mathbb P^1 \cup \mathbb P^1$, so that $Z$ is singular, but all of its points are smooth in $X$? Oh -- you're saying to blow up that point in $X$, where it's smooth, and that resolves the singularity in $Z$...

Comment: @Mohan It seems that a variation on the usual statement of resolution of singularities is needed. I wonder if this exists in the literature?

Comment: This is how Hironaka does it and is called embedded resolution of singularities. May be he does only the case when $X$ is smooth, but many variations exist.

Comment: @Mohan I am surprised by what you said. I thought embedded resolution of singularities could only produce a divisor with normal crossing. More precisely, I thought that if $X\subset Y$ is a (regular) open subset with closed complement $Z$, then there exists $f:Y'\rightarrow Y$ such that :

1) $Y'$ is regular
2) $f^{-1}(Z)$ (total transform) is a divisor with normal crossing
3) the strict transform of $Z$ is regular

But $X$ will always have $Y'\setminus f^{-1}(Z)$ as complement, which cannot made smooth.

Comment: For example, I don't believe that $X=\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\mathbb{A}^1$ have a projective closure with smooth complement.

Comment: @Roland I seem to have misunderstood the question. I was thinking of embedding $X$ in a projective variety $Y$ so that points of $Y-X$ are smooth on $Y$, not that $Y-X$ is smooth.